# Keep getting 500 error from HERE Isoline API

Tags: python, api, python-requests, here-olp

I'm using python requests. I tried both the example requests in the documentation and the requests I constructed myself -

```
import requests
requests.get('https://isoline.router.hereapi.com/v8/isolines?transportMode=car&range[type]=distance&range[values]=3000&origin=82.8628,135.00&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}'
```

I got the api keys following the steps [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/isoline-routing-api/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html)

And I keep getting "Response [500]", which the reference says means "Internal Server Error". When I paste the request in the browser, I get "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data". Any thoughts?

Comment: We can't possibly help you in any material way without seeing your code as a [mre], per our guidance on [ask].

Comment: @esqew thanks for the flag! Tweaked the code above, hope that does it?

Comment: To be clear, you've replaced `{YOUR_API_KEY}` in the example with the API key you've been issued, correct?

Comment: @esqew Yes. I have used APIs with issued keys before.